# Construct Maclaurin series for $f(x)=x\sin(2x)$ in sigma notation and use this to find $f^{(14)} (0)$ and $f^{(9)} (0)$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

So I used the known power series of $\sin(x)$ to get down to the Maclaurin in sigma notation.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n}(2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+2}$$

I'm a bit foggy on the $f^{(14)} (0)$ and $f^{(9)} (0)$ part.

I would think that I need to use the default Maclaurin series (not the derived one) and make $x^{14}$.  Of course my $x$ is $x^{2n+2}$.  So, should I use $n=7$?  Because $2n+2=14$ is $n=7$.

If this IS the case then shouldn't I be adjusting for the $2^{2n+1}$ on the $f()$ side?  And where would I go from there to solve?

Just a bit confused.  Open to viewing Youtube or Kahn if someone can link.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: the coefficients in front of monomials are actually derivatives at 0, divided by some factorial.
I.e. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n}(2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+2} = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}\times{x^2}+...$.

So all you have to do is to find the coefficients in front of monomials $x^9$ and $x^{14}$.

Comment: Oops..  pressed enter for a next line....  That makes a lot of sense.  My concern at this point is that the f() portion of my derived function doesn't seem to match the syntax of the f(0)...  It's got a 2^(2n+1) and a (2n+1)! in the denominator.  $\frac{(-1)^{n}(2)^{{(2n+1)}}}{(2n+1)!}$    I guess what I'm thinking is $x^{14}$ will be true when n=7 for the x side and that makes the f side $\frac{(-1)(2)^{{(15)}}}{(15)!}$ ...  Am I doing this right?

Comment: The fact that $xsin(2x)$ is an even function is used in that expansion. Because, of that observation all the coefficients in front of $x^k$ where $k$ is odd is 0. So we only need to take care of even monomials.